# Loosing cookie when swich from http to https

Tags: c#, http, cookies, https

I have the option in my site to change language.

When user change language ,its saved in cookie, so the other pages know which language to display!

Some of the pages are in https. And in these pages I don't get the selected language.

Is there any way to use the same cookie for `http` and `https`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843305/switching-between-http-and-https-pages-with-secure-session-cookie

Comment: Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2321224/1916110 - it can explain.

Comment: Offtopic: no solution to go to all HTTPS? http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. The cookies are local to the domain, and the http and https pages are considered to be in different domains.

The https pages are encrypted, so sending the same cookies for a http request would leak that information, and compromise the encryption.

Comment: From reading and my own testing I believe this is incorrect. Unless specified as secure, a cookie can be read over both http and https on the same domain.

Comment: @rrrr: Cookies are subject to the same-origin policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie), and the scheme (http: / https:) is part of what determines the origin (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 4):

You could try setting your cookie to secure = false

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure.aspx

[how can I share an asp.net session between http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567535/how-can-i-share-an-asp-net-session-between-http-and-https)